# PACT jvm matching rules are being ignored when running test

Tags: pact, pact-jvm

I'm using PACT JVM https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/provider/pact-jvm-provider-junit
I don't know why the matching rules in my contact are being ignored.
My HTTP test

```
@RunWith(SpringRestPactRunner.class) // Say JUnit to run tests with custom Runner
@Provider("provDataTest")// Set up name of tested provider
@PactBroker(host="pact-broker.services", port = "80")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT,
        properties = {"spring.profiles.active=dev"},
        classes = Application.class)
public class ContractTesting {

    private static String token;

    @BeforeClass //Method will be run once: before whole contract test suite
    public static void setUpService() {
        //Run DB, create schema
        //Run service
        //...
        System.out.println("Now service in default state");
    }

    @TargetRequestFilter
    public void exampleRequestFilter(HttpRequest request) {

    }

    @State("Check correct data json structure in case code: 401")
    public void checkDataInCaseUnauthorized() {

    }

    @TestTarget // Annotation denotes Target that will be used for tests
    public final Target target = new HttpTarget(8082);
```

And my Contract file

```
{
  "provider": {
    "name": "provDataTest"
  },
  "consumer": {
    "name": "test"
  },
  "interactions": [
    {
      "description": "Read all links_401",
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/v1/consumer/me/link_social_account",
        "headers": {
          "invalidAuth": "401"
        }
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 401,
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "text/json;charset=utf-8"
        },
        "body": {
          "error": {
            "code": 401,
            "message": "session incorrect",
            "errors": []
          }
        },
        "matchingRules": {
          "body": {
            "$.error": {
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "type"
                }
              ],
              "combine": "AND"
            },
            "$.error.code": {
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "integer"
                }
              ],
              "combine": "AND"
            },
            "$.error.message": {
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "type"
                }
              ],
              "combine": "AND"
            },
            "$.error.errors[*].message": {
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "type"
                }
              ],
              "combine": "AND"
            },
            "$.error.errors[*].field": {
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "type"
                }
              ],
              "combine": "AND"
            }
          },
          "header": {
            "Content-Type": {
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "text/json;charset=utf-8",
                  "regex": "regex"
                }
              ],
              "combine": "AND"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "providerStates": [
        {
          "name": "Check correct data json structure in case code: 401"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "pactSpecification": {
      "version": "3.0.0"
    },
    "pact-jvm": {
      "version": "3.2.11"
    }
  }
}
```

And show error after run

```
Read all links_401 returns a response which has a matching body
      Read all links_401 returns a response which has a matching
body=BodyComparisonResult(mismatches={/=[BodyMismatch(expected=[B@480e8a7a, actual=[B@10378c35, mismatch=Actual body '[B@10378c35' is not equal to the expected body '[B@480e8a7a', path=/, diff=null)]},
 diff=[-{"error":{"code":401,"message":"session incorrect","errors":[]}}, 
+{"error":{"code":401,"message":"session incorrect, please login again (CR_A1004)","errors":[]}}])
```

I have tried to change regex but the problem is still happening.
It is only correct when message data correct.

Please help to give my point incorrect.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your content-type header: `"Content-Type": "text/json;charset=utf-8"`. The proper content type for JSON payloads should be `application/json`. That is why the matchers are not being applied, because the body is being treated as a text payload. Just change the content type and then the body will be parsed as a JSON document and the matchers will be applied to the fields.